# Encrypt Mongodb with Google Cloud Key Management Service

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-kms

Is it possible to use `Google KMS` with `Mongodb` server on Ubuntu 18.04 (GCP) to encrypt data at rest? What are the requirements? How is it done? I want to use mongodb encryption feature for additional security.

The documentation mentions `KMIP` protocol and does Google provide such service?

ps: I have installed `Mongodb enterprise` edition on my server along with other services such as backend.

Answer (score 1):

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932890/encrypt-mongodb-with-google-cloud-key-management-service#comment104125392_58933100) and assuming your questions is on regards of how to use the KMS integration with MongoDB:

For a start, [it is possible to use KMS with MongoDB](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/how-our-customers-are-using-mongodb-atlas-on-google-cloud-platform). Google even [provides an out-of-the-box solution of MongoDB Atlas](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/) to integrate with KMS via Market Place.

However, this integration is not available on [Atlas M0, M2 and M5](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-gcp-kms/).

You can follow the same [link](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-gcp-kms/) for details on how to use the integration. If you have any specific question on this integration, please edit your question to include it.

Comment: This is about mongodb atlas, isn't? But I want to encrypt the mongodb running on my server.

Comment: Please provide what specifically want to achieve. Details on how to use KMS with MongoDB are in my answer and regarding data encryption at rest were [provided by Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58933100/10892354). I suggest asking [specific questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the accuracy of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Data on GCP is [always encrypted at rest](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/). You can optionally use your own KMS keys to [encrypt the disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-managed-encryption).

```
gcloud compute disks create encrypted-disk \
  --kms-key projects/[KMS_PROJECT_ID]/locations/[REGION]/keyRings/[KEY_RING]/cryptoKeys/[KEY]
```

Comment: My question may not clear(sorry). I want to use mongodb encryption feature for additional security.